# python criptografando, poderiam me ajudar a diminuir o código?

Tags: python, codificação-de-caracteres

python criptografando, poderiam me ajudar a diminuir o código?

```
def criptografar(frase):
    tradutor = ""
    for letra in frase:
        if letra in "Aa":
            tradutor = tradutor + "@"
        elif letra in "Bb":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Cc":
            tradutor = tradutor + "!"
        elif letra in "Dd":
            tradutor = tradutor + "$"
        elif letra in "Ee":
            tradutor = tradutor + "%"
        elif letra in "Ff":
            tradutor = tradutor + "&"
        elif letra in "Gg":
            tradutor = tradutor + "1"
        elif letra in "Hh":
            tradutor = tradutor + "2"
        elif letra in "Ii":
            tradutor = tradutor + "3"
        elif letra in "Jj":
            tradutor = tradutor + "4"
        elif letra in "Kk":
            tradutor = tradutor + "5"
        elif letra in "Ll":
            tradutor = tradutor + "6"
        elif letra in "Ii":
            tradutor = tradutor + "6"
        elif letra in "Mm":
            tradutor = tradutor + "7"
        elif letra in "Nn":
            tradutor = tradutor + "8"
        elif letra in "Oo":
            tradutor = tradutor + "9"
        elif letra in "Pp":
            tradutor = tradutor + "0"
        elif letra in "Qq":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Rr":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Ss":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Tt":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Ww":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Xx":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Hh":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Yy":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        elif letra in "Zz":
            tradutor = tradutor + "#"
        else:
            tradutor = tradutor + letra
    return tradutor 
print(criptografar(input("Digite o texto a ser Criptografado ")))
```

Comment: Por que tem duas vezes o H e nenhuma vez o U?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar um dicionário em que as chaves são os caracteres da entrada e o valor são os caracteres para qual quer "criptografar". Usando o `dict` com `zip` o código fica bastante simples:

```py
def criptografar(entrada):
    antes = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstwxuyz'
    depois = '@#!$%&1234567890#########'

    tabela = dict(zip(antes, depois))

    return ''.join(tabela.get(letra.lower(), letra) for letra in entrada)
```